# How to make particular text in a cell Bold and Underlined

Tags: vba, excel

```
 strProject = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 2).Value)
       On Error Resume Next
       Set objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets("" & strProject & "")
       If Not objWorkSheet Is Nothing Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Value = Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(12, 6).Value)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 6).Value = "Highlights for current week:" + Chr(10) + Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(22, 2).Value) + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + "Action Plan for next Week:" + Chr(10) + Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(27, 2).Value)
```

How do I make "Highlights for current week:" bold and underlined?

Comment: Your question makes no sense - a string wouldn't make the cell bold or underlined, and there is other text in the cell that you haven't said if you want to change also

Comment: I need only the particular text "Highlights for current week:" in the cell to be bold and underline

Could you hard code the above property and reply please?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.  The bold and italic properties belong to the [Font object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840959.aspx), which can be accessed via a [range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

**Example**

```
ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
ActiveCell.Font.Italic = True
```

This example updates the currently active cell.

**Updated**

If you only want to apply a style to part of a cell the syntax is a little different.

**Partial Formatting Example**

```
ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1 Length:=10).Font.Bold = True
```

The start and length parameters control which characters are shown in bold.

Did you know Excel can write the VBA for you?  Look for the macro recorder in the bottom left corner.  When active Excel will translate your manual actions into VBA.  This is a great way to discover the required code.

Comment: I need only the particular text "Highlights for current week:" in the cell to be bold and underline Could you hard code the above property and reply please?